# How to pass the sessions and sessions auth of the App laravel to package And vice versa?

Tags: laravel

Do you know how to pass the sessions and session auth of the App laravel to package, and vice versa?  It does not work for me, I do not know what I'm missing. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you try the global `session()` function from Laravel? Check it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#retrieving-data

Comment: Have you got any code you were working with? Show us

Comment: @Gayan, Do not authenticate in the package, what I lack know ?  http://i.imgur.com/1itzNCV.png

Comment: Are you loading separate route file for package instead of default one?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar,  Routes within the same package, as I am new in packages I do not know if I'm missing any configuration to pass the session img ->>http://i.imgur.com/D09BQ56.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the image you have provided it looks like they have registered separate route file instead of default one.

Try wrapping the routes inside the web middleware like

```
Route::group([middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    //Your routes here
});
```

Without the web middleware your session won't work.

Comment: So simple, thank you very very much, as I am new in this I lack more knowledge, I speak Spanish I apologize the regular English,

Comment: No issues. If my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted so that others might find it useful :)

Comment: Correct, I would give you points but I need 15 reputation to do it < 3